# What is the logic behind reputation deduction?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

I have just noticed that my reputations are deducted without any reason.

[image]

The shown links are not clickable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You edited these and got +2 rep for each.  The Community user deleted some closed and negatively voted questions yesterday, and these were among the casualties.  As a result you lost the rep.

Comment: This is right: Reputation gained for an approved suggested edit is lost when the post is deleted.

Comment: Thanks, this happen first time in 6 months. or maybe i didn't notice before.