# Why my reputation decrease without any message?

Tags: discussion, support

My reputation decrease by -2 without any message and I checked this [Post](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/what-is-the-logic-behind-reputation-deduction), it show the message **removed** for the deleted or closed post. But I'm not getting any message for the lost reputation. How can I check the lost reputation ? or Is this bug ?

for reference, today my rep is 2113 and now it showing 2111. See the below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Below is the screenshot for **reputation details without message for lost rep**.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select *show removed posts* at the bottom of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12418/bala?tab=reputation. Once you check it, you will see you got 4 points removed for suggested edits for [two](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84743/i-upgrade-drupal-7-23-and-ubercart-7-x-3-5-after-booking-is-completed-on-confir) [questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86641/how-to-find-the-if-the-url-has-image-or-not-using-curl) that got deleted

Comment: thanks kiamlaluno, I never noticed the checkbox at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

A question that you edited, giving you 2 rep points, was deleted.

As a result, you lost the 2 rep points you originally earned from the edit.

It shows up in your reputation history when I look at your profile, so it should show for you there too

Comment: see my updated post, I can't see the -2 rep message.

Comment: where do you checked my lost rep, I can't find it

Comment: Clive thanks, I never noticed the checkbox at the bottom. I think this should be enabled by default, when a user is registered.